# Glassfish Server administrator password accidently removed

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have Netbeans 7.4 & GlassFish Server 4.0, I've accidently removed the password in server properties..

now everytime I start Netbeans a message box pops up saying

> Authorization failed while checking GlassFish Server status, Please provide valid administrator credentials

and it asks me for username and password

the password seemed to be auto-generated, I've tried to login with admin and leave the password blank or admin as a password, it didn't work.

I also tried to permanently remove and re download it again in Netbeans, I got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per http://it.i88.ca/2012/07/glassfish-3-solution-recovery-admin.html
you can change the content of glassfish/domains/domain1/config/admin-keyfile to

```
admin;{SSHA256}dvCEGFNHGtSyXIhJvwR5FnviH+u8fCadrUIqp6uJc1tP9Bv10CGT7A==;asadmin
```

and your asadmin password is now "changeit".